# Dijkstra's Algorithm prints most recent predecessor path instead of shortest

Tags: java, dijkstra

Currently, my printing function prints the path of the most recently visited nodes to the destination instead of the shortest path. For example if the shortest path is a,c,e , with a = 1 c = 1, e = 4, and another path is a,d,e with weights a = 1, d = 4, e = 4, my algorithm travels in this direction: a,c,d,e but would print a d e since those were visited recently and my setPredecessor() method is set for a bad predecessor. Any ideas on this would be greatly appreciative, either to fix my current code or attempt this in a different manner.

```
class ShortestPathFinder {
        private  Graph graph = new Graph();
        private  Vertex source = new Vertex(0, null);
        private Vertex destination = new Vertex(0,null);
        private  Map<Vertex,Vertex> previousVertex = new HashMap();

    public void  findShortestPath(Graph graph, Vertex source, Vertex destination, ReadInput graphReader) {
        this.destination = destination;
        this.source = source;

        source.setDistanceFromSource(0);
        PriorityQueue<Vertex> priorityQueue = new PriorityQueue<>();
        priorityQueue.add(source);
        source.setVisited(true);
        boolean destinationFound = false;

        while( !priorityQueue.isEmpty() && destinationFound == false){
            // Getting the minimum distance vertex from priority queue
            Vertex actualVertex = priorityQueue.poll();
            System.out.println("working on: " + actualVertex.getID());

            actualVertex = graphReader.SetAdjList(actualVertex);


            for(Edge edge : actualVertex.getAdjacenciesList()){
                Vertex v = edge.getTargetVertex();
                System.out.println("a Neighbor is: " + v.getID());
                if(!v.isVisited()) {
                    if(v.getID() == destination.getID() || edge.getStartVertex().getID() == destination.getID()) {
                        System.out.println("Destination found");
                            destination.setPredecessor(actualVertex);
                            destination.setDistanceFromSource(actualVertex.getDistanceFromSource() + edge.getWeight());
                            destinationFound = true;
                            break;  
                    }
                    double newDistance = actualVertex.getDistanceFromSource() + edge.getWeight();

                    if( newDistance < v.getDistanceFromSource() ){
                        priorityQueue.remove(v);
                        v.setDistanceFromSource(newDistance);
                        v.setPredecessor(actualVertex);
                        priorityQueue.add(v);
                        System.out.println("Added: " + v.getID());
                    }
                }
            }
            actualVertex.setVisited(true);
        }       
    }

    public List<Vertex> getPath() {
        List<Vertex> path = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Vertex vertex=destination;vertex!=null;vertex=vertex.getPredecessor()){
                path.add(vertex);
        }
        Collections.reverse(path);
        return path;
    }       
}
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the lines `destinationFound = true;` and `break;`?  I don't believe standard implementations of Dijkstra's necessarily stop when the destination is found the first time and instead keep searching to ensure the absolute shortest path is found.

Comment: Standard implementations don't, I only am using them so my program doesn't run on as my "graph" is incredibly large, removing them leaves me with the same result. I may try more input cases, I believe the test case I am basing my code of of might not be computed correctly.